# Any point of having static variables inside a singleton class?

Tags: c++

I have a singleton class as follows,

```
class Design {
 private:
  Design();
  static const int TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_TRIANGLES = 21;

 public:
  const static Design& getInstance();
```

My question is, since a singleton class will always have a single instance, is there any point of declaring any member variable as `static`?

Here, in this example, even though, `TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_TRIANGLES` is always 21 and I want all instances of `Design` to share this, should I even care, since there is only ever going to be 1 instance, right?

Comment: Probably comes down to a style choice. I don't, personally. You are correct that the singleton exists in one place. The only gray area would be in cases where you might destroy and rebuild the singleton. For example, in unit-testing. In that case, it _might_ matter whether members are static or not, as that can affect whether they are initialized once only, or every time a new singleton is created.

Comment: This particular member is a constexpr. You cannot have a constexpr non-static member.

Comment: It may cause difference also at platform with limited resources (or when variable has significant memory footprint). If the variable ends up requiring actual memory instance, the static ones may end up in different memory section (probably allocated by OS executable loader or fixed memory address in bare metal) than member ones (part of the member instance, probably heap memory dynamically allocated), which may cause difference in how quickly you run out of resources.

In any case, singletons and mutable static variables are pain especially in unit testing, consider avoiding it.

Comment: Both singletons and globals are usufally design problems already. Learn about abstract baseclasses (interfaces) and dependency injection to avoid them.

Answer (score -1):

Try to avoid global variables and or singletons by using dependency injection.
Example :

```
#include <utility>

// For real (compile time) constants you can make a header file 
// with a namespace and put constexpr values in it.
namespace my_namespace::constants
{
    // this way your constants are really compile time constants
    inline constexpr std::size_t TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_TRIANGLES = 21;
}

// For previous singleton and global data declare an interface (or interfaces)
// providing access to the "global" data or singleton functionality.
// this allows for various implementations (inlcuding mocks and stubs for unit testing)
class DesignItf
{
public:
    virtual ~DesignItf() = default;
    virtual int get_some_config_value() const noexcept = 0;

protected:
    DesignItf() = default;
};


// A class implementing your previous singleton
// or providing access to runtime "globals"
class Design :
    public DesignItf
{
public:
    int get_some_config_value() const noexcept { return 42; };
};

// refactored code that previously used a singleton (or accessed global data)
class SomeClassPreviouslyUsingGlobalOrSingleton
{
public:
    // used dependency injection!
    explicit SomeClassPreviouslyUsingGlobalOrSingleton(const DesignItf& design)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Design design; // your previous singleton is now just a normal class with very well determined lifetime.
    SomeClassPreviouslyUsingGlobalOrSingleton c{ design }; // inject the dependency
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of bloat to do the same thing just slower. Singletons and globals are fine to use when designed correctly, and dependency-injection is just as dangerous and can also easily lead to strange bugs.
Also in no way does that even relate to what was asked.

Comment: Do you have experience with large unit testable projects? Have you heard about the initialization order fiasco. (Try that one with dynamic loadabable libraries).  Strange bugs, never seen them, only stupid bugs due to not designing or implemening lifecycles correctly (millions of lines of code with a lot of threads).And in my mind it is related to the question. Asking for ways to correctly jump in front of a bus can be answered with "don't jump in front of the bus in the first place" ;)

Comment: Yes i have experience with that. That is my job.
IOF is a solved problem....  And you give a n answer that is more code, no less fragile, and does not offer any real benefits either.